# open Camera Roll from Java Script method in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

I have requirement to load one JSP/HTML5 page in UIWebView. In this page there is link for attachment and on click of that I need to open CameraRoll to select file and then upload it to server. This is same like we do attachment in email. Now problem is from Java Script how do I open CameraRoll? My main query is that is it possible to open CameraRoll from Java Script without calling Native iOS methods. Java Script to open dialog is embedded in JSP/HTML5 page.

Let me know if you find that above information is not enough so I will try to give you more detail. Ultimately I have one page in UIWebView which should work like sending some message to user with attachment from CameraRoll like we do in normal email app.

I searched a lot on net but couldnt find any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in iOS6, you can access the Media Capture API which allows you to request files from the user via `<input type="file" />`.

Essentially, all you need to do is include an `<input type="file" />` and when the user touches the input, it will open the phone's camera roll.

Once the user has selected the file, you can send the file using the POST form action or AJAX, or use the File API to manipulate the file data on the client side. Check out the [HTML Media Capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) specification from the W3C for more information on implemention.

Comment: thanks for reply. I will forward this to my team member and come back to you if any issue. I have one query that above solution only works for iOS6 or will it work for iOS SDK version 5.1 also?

Comment: iOS6+ only. File upload & HTML Media Capture isn't supported pre-iOS6.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Yes it is working fine and also it is only for iOS6+. My question is properly answered here and solution is working fine for me

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as correct then if this solves your problem.